# Using an rlang alternative to eval in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, rlang

In my below function, I was wondering if there is an `rlang` alternative to `eval()`?

```
library(rlang)

foo <- function(dat, ..., i){
  
  dot_cols <- rlang::ensyms(...)[[1]] 
  subset(dat, eval(dot_cols) == i)    # <--- what to use instead of eval()
}

foo(dat=mtcars, vs, i=0)
```

Comment: If there are more than one column, it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to convert the unquoted variadic column names to string, then use `filter` with `if_all` (or `if_any` - depends on whether all the columns or any in a row should satisfy the condition)

```
foo <- function(dat, ..., i){
  
  dot_cols <- purrr::map_chr(rlang::ensyms(...), rlang::as_string)
  dat %>%
     filter(if_all(all_of(dot_cols), ~ .x== i))
}
```

-testing

```
> foo(dat=mtcars, vs, am, i=0)
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
> foo(dat=mtcars, vs, i=0)
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

---

If there is only a single column,

```
foo <- function(dat, colnm, i){
  
  dot_col <- rlang::ensym(colnm) 
   filter(dat, !!(dot_col) == i) 
}
```

-testing

```
> foo(mtcars, vs, i = 0)
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4           21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

The above function can take either quoted or unquoted column name.  If it is always unquoted, then can use `{{}}`

```
foo <- function(dat, colnm, i){  
  
   filter(dat, {{colnm}} == i) 
}
foo(mtcars, vs, i = 0)
```

Comment: @SimonHarmel My solution is more general, in case you want to pass more than one

Comment: @SimonHarmel `ensym`/s` convert to symbol/symbols, so you need just `!!` or `!!!`.  if there are more than one column, the `==` wouldn't work as expected

Comment: @SimonHarmel yes, because the tidyverse functions work within the framework of those functions, `subset` is a base R function

Comment: Dear Arun, [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73341679/16762740) is a question regarding data.frame subsetting.