# Find rows that have closest columns' values to a specific row in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, subset

Imagine we have one row in the `data` below as our `reference` (row # 116).

How can I find any other rows in this `data` whose columns' values are **the same or the closest (if column value is numerical, lets say up to +/- 3 is an acceptable match)** to the columns' values of this `reference` row?

For example, if the column value for variable `prof` in the `reference` row is `beginner`, we want  to find another row whose value for `prof` is also `beginner`.

Or if the column value for variable `study_length` in the `reference` row is `5`, we want  to find another row whose value for `study_length` is also `5 +/- 3` and so on.

Is it possible to set up a function do this in R?

```
data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hkil/m/master/wcf.csv")[-c(2:6,12,17)])

reference <- data[116,]

############################# YOUR POSSIBLE ANSWER:

foo <- function(data = data, reference_row = 116, tolerance_for_numerics = 3) {

# your solution


}

# Example of use:

foo()
```

Comment: In addition to the data.table approach you can also install the `fuzzyjoin` package. And do this search: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+closest+column

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+fuzzy+merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution.

```r
foo <- function(x = data, reference_row = 116, tolerance_for_numerics = 3) {
  # which columns are numeric
  i <- sapply(x, is.numeric)
  reference <- x[reference_row, ]
  # numeric columns are within a range
  num <- mapply(\(y, ref, tol) {
    y >= ref - tol & y <= ref + tol
  }, data[i], reference[i], MoreArgs = list(tol = 3))
  # other columns must match exactly (?)
  other <- mapply(\(y, ref) {
    y == ref
  }, data[!i], reference[!i])
  which(rowSums(cbind(other, num)) == ncol(data))
}

data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hkil/m/master/wcf.csv")[-c(2:6,12,17)]

# Example of use:
foo()
#> [1] 112 114 116
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I can reopen if you so desire.

Comment: @AnilGoyal : I think it's basically a duplicate of many questions some with accepted answers and I know the fuzzyjoin package has functions that do all of the requested operations. So I don't think the questioner did sufficient searching.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, the `foo()` is not working when the data has 1+ numeric colmuns!! see `foo(x=starwars[, 2:6], reference_row = 5, tolerance_for_numerics = 3)`

Comment: @IRTFM, Ok thanks, I will have a look there again.  At first I found some differences in requirements mentioned therefore I voted to re-open.  Thanks again

Comment: @AniGoyal If the OP edits the question to indicate effort at using the existing questions with answers and showing the code that failed, I will vote to reopen as well.

Comment: @AnilGoyal Bug corrected, `reference <- x[reference_row, ]` had `data` instead of `x`.